# Split a string's digits every 3rd digit

Tags: python, string, split, python-3.4

I have this string

```
s = '4294967296'
```

I want to split this into

```
4.294.967.296
```

Basically I want to insert a dot every 3rd digit. How can I do this? I tried

```
c = '4294967296'

for x,y in enumerate(c[::-1]):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        b = c[:x] + '.' + c[:x]
print (b)
```

But the output was

```
>>> 
42949672.42949672
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (ab)use string formatting:

```
s = '4294967296'
t = format(int(s), ',').replace(',', '.')
# '4.294.967.296'
```